# SIGABRT when using NSDateComponents

Tags: objective-c, sigabrt

```
NSDate *myDate = [[messagesCopy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] date];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:myDate]; // CRASH

cell.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", (int)[components month]];
```

The error messages:

2014-06-16 12:57:17.706 OrgBeac[2828:60b] -[Message sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e55010
2014-06-16 12:57:17.709 OrgBeac[2828:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Message sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e55010'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e6f4fd3 0x38f6dccf 0x2e6f8967 0x2e6f7253 0x2e6f84f8 0xad603 0xad9c3 0x31020a2b 0x30fe569f 0x30fe73fd 0x30fe7351 0x30fe6f45 0xace8b 0x2f0e56d1 0x39324cef 0x393222ad 0x39321319 0x2f0e3cb9 0x2f0e3f41 0x2f0e40b7 0x2f0e41b5 0xac6a1 0x2f033fc3 0x2f033f07 0x2f033e21 0x2e35b0e7 0x2e359cf7 0x2e628941 0x2e2f16bb 0x2e2f1579 0x2e2f140d 0x2e6c025b 0x2e6bf72b 0x2e6bdf1f 0x2e628f0f 0x2e628cf3 0x33581663 0x30f7416d 0xab1d7 0x3947aab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Aaaand what is the error message?

Comment: What crash you are getting?

Comment: I think myDate is a bad pointer. Please check what you are getting from [[messagesCopy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] date]

Comment: @Naga Mallesh Maddali, you were right, thank you

Comment: ....the error message would have told you just that!

Comment: @Mario, I added the errors to the description

Comment: The code and the exception reason don't match.  I don't believe it's crashing where you say it is.